# Указатели и функция

Tags: c

Как правильно разименовать эти указатели, почему пишет , что не получается операция записи?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long double* fn(float* z1, double* z2)
{
   long double* zz;
   zz = (log(--z1)/z2);
   return zz;
}

int main()
{ 
  float aa;
  double bb;
  long double* p1;
  float* p2=&aa;
  double* p3=&bb;

  aa = 10; bb = 15;

  p1 = fn(p2, p3);
  printf("fn=%.3f", p1);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Gh0stik, @alexlz написал Вам правильную функцию, осталось ее 1) правильно вызвать (например fn(p2+1,p3)) и 2) правильно напечатать результат ( \* перед p1 в printf набейте).

Comment: В соответствии с правилами хорошего тона, после printf надо ещё включить free(p1);

Answer (score 2):

Разыменовывание указателя производится такой же звёздочкой. Это

zz = (log(--z1)/z2);

надо заменить на

```
zz = (log(--(*z1))/(*z2));
```

То есть, поскольку функция принимает не вещественные числа, а указатели на них, надо брать не значения указателей (т.е. числовые представления адресов, на которые они указывают), а то, что находится по этим адресам.

Функция у Вас тоже возвращает указатель. По идее, в переменную zz надо записать не число, которое возвращает выражение `(log(--(*z1))/(*z2))`, а адрес переменной, в которую это число будет записано. Только, скорее всего, как только Вы выйдете из этой функции и попробуете разыменовать этот указатель, Вы получите ошибку доступа к памяти, т.к. указатель будет указывать на фрейм стека, который после выхода из функции будет неиспользуемым.

Comment: Ну ошибки доступа к памяти вроде быть не должно, но вот результат может быть весьма неожиданным. Т.е. для такой функции память под результат надо размещать в куче (c-malloc, c++-new) и после использования освобождать.


   long double* fn(float* z1, double* z2)
   {
       long double* zz = malloc(sizeof(long double));
       *zz = (log(*--z1)/ *z2);
       return zz;
   }

Comment: Исправил код функции на выше приведенную и получил ошибку в строке
long double* zz = malloc(sizeof(long double));

Comment: Ошибка вызвана тем, что нет прототипа ф. malloc (находится в stdlib.h). Кроме того, если компилятор с c++, то правильней использовать не malloc/free а new/delete, и строка соответственно будет


       long double* zz = new long double;

Comment: @Gh0stik , malloc возвращает указатель типа void*. С++ требует явного приведения типов указателей, поэтому нужно писать

`long double* zz = (long double*) malloc(sizeof(long double));`

Comment: Разумеется C++, а насчёт void* -> long double* я стормозил. Но уж ежели c++, тогда static_cast<long double *>(...)

Answer (score 1):

Переменная zz внутри функции должна ссылаться на какой-то блок памяти, который нужно выделить функцией malloc. Чтобы присвоить значение переменной, а не указателю на нее, нужно использовать *zz=..., и точно так же чтобы получить значения z1 и z2.
Плюс для вывода long double лучше использовать %Lf, хотя на винде long double и double вроде не отличаются.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long double* fn(float* z1, double* z2)
{
   long double *zz = (long double*)malloc(sizeof(*zz));
   *zz = (log(--*z1)/(*z2));
   return zz;
}

int main()
{
  float aa;
  double bb;
  long double* p1;
  float* p2=&aa;
  double* p3=&bb;

  aa = 10; bb = 15;

  p1 = fn(p2, p3);
  printf("fn= %.3Lf\n", (long double)*p1);
  free(p1);
  scanf("");
  return 0;
}
```